# How to convert live javascript variables to php variables?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm extremely new to this so please excuse my spaghetti code - I'm trying to make a webpage that keeps track of basketball statistics live during a game, and then saves the total statistics using php afterwards. For now, I just need to pass the variable that is being live updated from my html page to php at the press of a button. I'm pretty sure I'm not even close, but am getting the 'undefined index' message when trying this. Here is my html page:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scoring</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var points = 0;
    var assists = 0;
    var rebounds = 0;
    function add1point(){
      points++;
      document.getElementById('displaypoints').innerHTML = '<p>Points: ' + points;
    }
    function add2points(){
      points = points + 2;
      document.getElementById('displaypoints').innerHTML = '<p>Points: ' + points;
    }
    function add3points(){
      points = points + 3;
      document.getElementById('displaypoints').innerHTML = '<p>Points: ' + points;
    }
    function add1assist(){
      assists++;
      document.getElementById('displayassists').innerHTML = '<p>Assists: ' + assists;
    }
    function add1rebound(){
      rebounds++;
      document.getElementById('displayrebounds').innerHTML = '<p>Rebounds: ' + rebounds;
    }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <center>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add1point()">+1 Point (Made Free-Throw)</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add2points()">+2 Points (Made Field-Goal)</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add3points()">+3 Points (Made Three-Pointer)</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add1assist()">+1 Assist</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add1rebound()">+1 (Offensive) Rebound</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add1rebound()">+1 (Defensive) Rebound</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<form method="post" attribute="post" action="scoring.php">
    <div id="displaypoints"><script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>Points: ' + points);</script></div>
    <div id="displayassists"><script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>Assists: ' + assists);</script></div>
    <div id="displayrebounds"><script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>Rebounds: ' + rebounds);</script></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Finish Game">
</button>
</form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And my php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game Finished</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$points = $_POST['points'];
$assists= $_POST['assists'];
$rebounds = $_POST["rebounds"];
?>
</p>
</body>
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your form needs `<input>` fields called "points", "assists" and "rebounds" with the appropriate values.

Comment: @James Can you give an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote some parts of your code. I hope you don't mind :).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Scoring</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addPoints(1)">+1 Point (Made Free-Throw)</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addPoints(2)">+2 Points (Made Field-Goal)</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addPoints(3)">+3 Points (Made Three-Pointer)</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addAssists(1)">+1 Assist</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addRebounds(1)">+1 (Offensive) Rebound</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="addRebounds(1)">+1 (Defensive) Rebound</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <form method="post" attribute="post" action="scoring.php">
                <p>Points: <span id="displaypoints"></span></p>
                <p>Assists: <span id="displayassists"></span></p>
                <p>Rebounds: <span id="displayrebounds"></span></p>

                <!-- Any input element with "name" attribute will be sent to server (scoring.php script). -->
                <input type="hidden" name="points" id="points" />

                <!-- Any input element with "name" attribute will be sent to server (scoring.php script). -->
                <input type="hidden" name="assists" id="assists" />

                <!-- Any input element with "name" attribute will be sent to server (scoring.php script). -->
                <input type="hidden" name="rebounds" id="rebounds" />

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Finish Game">
            </form>
        </center>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Initial values
            var points = 0;
            var assists = 0;
            var rebounds = 0;

            // Find "span" element with "displaypoints" id.
            $displayPoints = $("#displaypoints");
            // Set element text to initial points value.
            $displayPoints.text(points);

            // Find "span" element with "displayassists" id.
            $displayAssists = $("#displayassists"),
            // Set element text to initial assists value.
            $displayAssists.text(assists);

            // Find "span" element with "displayrebounds" id.
            $displayRebounds = $("#displayrebounds");
            // Set element text to initial rebounds value.
            $displayRebounds.text(rebounds);

            // Function that receives the amount of points.
            // 1. Adds received amount of points to current amount of points.
            // 2. Sets the corresponding element text to current amount of points.
            // 3. Sets the element that's going to be sent to server value to current amount of points.
            function addPoints(amount){
                points += amount;
                $displayPoints.text(points);
                $("#points").val(points);
            }

            // Function that receives the amount of assists.
            // 1. Adds received amount of assists to current amount of assists.
            // 2. Sets the corresponding element text to current amount of assists.
            // 3. Sets the element that's going to be sent to server value to current amount of assists.
            function addAssists(amount){
                assists += amount;
                $displayAssists.text(assists);
                $("#assists").val(assists);
            }

            // Function that receives the amount of rebounds.
            // 1. Adds received amount of rebounds to current amount of rebounds.
            // 2. Sets the corresponding element text to current amount of rebounds.
            // 3. Sets the element that's going to be sent to server value to current amount of rebounds.
            function addRebounds(amount){
                rebounds += amount;
                $displayRebounds.text(rebounds);
                $("#rebounds").val(rebounds);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As James' comment said you could do it easily by inputs in your form. I guess you do not want that the user may change the value at the finish of the game, so you could use input hidden, something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="scoring.php">
    <div id="displaypoints"><script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p>Points: ' + points+'</p><input type="hidden" name="points" value="'+points+'">');</script></div>
    ...
<input type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Finish Game">
```